# Moving 1 column into several columns based on an empty row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to tidy up a spreadsheet from Google Sheets, essentially I only have two columns (date and value) but 3 different sets of data (separated by an empty row). I want to be able to grab everything after (in between) each empty row and paste it to the corresponding column. For example:

```
1 26
2 12
3 50
(empty row)
1 23
2 21
3 25
(empty row)
1 23
2 29
3 78
```

And I'd want it to be like this:

```
1 26 1 23 1 23
2 12 2 21 2 29
3 50 3 25 3 78
```

I've found some functions for detecting empty rows but wasn't sure where to go from there, sorry I'm a novice at Excel/Google Sheets. Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Here is a link to my sample spreadsheet (tab 1 is the sample data, tab 2 is what I'm trying to achieve)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp0Vk-_8T4bMcg-m0cGKq2ZvpLcJd9Y5jQS4Q8RD0Wo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a sample spreadsheet) with enough *realistic* data to illustrate both the problem you are trying to solve and the goal. Be clear about where in that spreadsheet you would want the results to be placed (starting cell, same sheet or a separate sheet?). As it is currently, you just have data floating in space, and that leaves too much guesswork (and extra work) for the volunteer contributors here. Help us help you by sharing a link.

Comment: Hi, here's a link to a sample of the spreadsheet. The first tab is what I start with, and the second tab is what I'm trying to achieve.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp0Vk-_8T4bMcg-m0cGKq2ZvpLcJd9Y5jQS4Q8RD0Wo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 IF(A1:A15="", "×", A1:A15), B1:B15}),,9^9)), 
 " ", "¤"), "¤$", ),,9^9), "×")), " "),,9^9)), " ¤"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula:

```
=arrayformula(split(transpose(split(join(",", flatten(
 query(transpose(split(flatten(split(regexreplace(join("×", A1:A11&","&B1:B11), "×,×", "★"), "★")), "×")), 
 "select Col1, Col2, Col3, '×' label '×' ''", 0))), "×")), ","))
```

#### Output:

[image]